# Android: Right approach for sensing the distance between current location and some point of interest?

Tags: android, google-maps, distance, android-geofence

I have a question regarding my programming approach for android - whether it's efficient or not. Just to give you an idea what I try to accomplish:

There are multiple points of interests on a map. If the user gets nearer to a PIT, a notification about the distance shall appear. There are let's say 3 notifications: At a distance of 1 mile, 0.5 miles and 0.1 mile. When the user is more or less exactly at the PIT, no more notifications are shown. The user is supposed to drive a car or another vehicle.

I'm currently using Geofences to detect whether the user has entered a radius of 1 mile. If so, I check the distance of his current location to the PIT. If it's about 0.5 or 0.1 miles away, a notification is fired. Therefore, I check the current location frequently (right now every 10 seconds). If the user is like at the PIT or rather very close, the Geofence is exited and done.

The code is working fine and this approach is the first thing that came to my mind while reading the Android Developer's tutorials etc. But is there another approach that is MORE EFFICIENT?

Although this is (currently) meeting my needs, I have two major concerns:

1. It seems to drain the battery quite a lot. Since the user is most likely to be in a car where he can charge his phone during usage, this might be less of a problem.
2. I read the number of PITs from a file on the SD card. In my example I have just a few PITs. But the user is able to modify the source data so that he can add as many as he wants to. Google says that only 100 active Geofences are supported per user. But what if my user has more than 100 PITs? Since I'm using a Geofence to sense whether I have to fire the first notification or not - this is a severe problem. So is there an alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a few suggestions :

1) To lower the amount of gps fixes, you could calculate a sleep time. The idea is to do frequent gps fixes when near a 'border' and few when far away. This could be further enhanced by taking the speed parameter returned by the GPS into account. 
If for instance the user is 20 miles from the nearest border while driving 20mph, you can easily wait 30 minutes before turning on the gps again, just to give a simple example.

2) I have run in to the same problem. My solution was simply to select only the POI's within X miles. This way ensuring never to risk hitting the limit of 100. When the user has moved (X-1) miles from his initial position, the  geofences are rebuild using the new location. 
If you think there is a high risk of having such a high density of points that the above strategy still might fall,  I would consider making your own proximity checking entirely based on gps instead of geofences.

Comment: I've also a question regarding the limit of 100. Taking the Android Developers page as a source, it's not 100% clear to me what the limit of 100 means. Can I only have 100 active Geofences at the same time? Or can I only have a total number of 100 different Geofences for my entire application?

Comment: In my experience it is a limit of 100 concurrent active geofences in your application. That is also why it works for me to rebuild the geofences as the total amount of active geofences never exceed 100 . By active I mean registered for the OS to monitor, so the state of the geofence is irrelevant.